# Laravel 5.1 Blade -- image as link

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I want to create link with HTML::link function using image loaded with HTML::image and it points to URL::route. So far this is what i came up with

```
{!! HTML::link( URL::route('/'), HTML::image("img.png", "Logo", array('height'=>'14','width'=>'86','border'=>'0'))) !!}
```

the link works, but the image doesn't.. it always came up as this:

`<img src="http://1.2.3.4/img.png" height="14" width="86" border="0" alt="Logo">`

but it never shows the image, even though I'm able to access the image from my browser.. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below code 
`<a href="#">{{ HTML::image("img/logo.png", "Logo") }}</a>`

Because, link() uses entities to escape the title

or simple use this 
For L4 
`{{ html_entity_decode( HTML::link("#", HTML::image("img/logo.png", "Logo") ) ) }}`

For L5

{!! html_entity_decode( HTML::link("#", HTML::image("img/logo.png", "Logo") ) ) !!}

Comment: you r using laravel 5 then the use this  {!! html_entity_decode( HTML::link("#", HTML::image("img/logo.png", "Logo") ) ) !!}